# Using OAuth2 with iOS 7

Tags: ios7, oauth-2.0

Does anyone know a reliable library I can use to allow OAuth authentication within my iOS7 app?  I've been searching for the last 2 days and can't find anything that works.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the OAuth2Client project before and it worked for me. https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client

Comment: That's one I was trying and couldn't quite get to work.  Do you mind if I talked to you offline about it?  I have a few questions and it might get lengthy here